# Can i create the graphical shapes objects in to the HTML5 canvas and How to show the cursor as pointer when user mouse over on the shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html5-canvas

Actually i want to create timeline in which there is the train of sections which user can scroll for checking, these sections are represented as a train of rectangular shapes and each such section need to have a connection to the events which is again repersented like a verticaly connected tooptips cycle.

Here i want to have there sections and events as a graphical objects such that i can show pop to the user regarding respective event information.

Is there any way to create graphical shape its object in javascript. 
Also i didnt find the way to show the cursor as a pointer when user moves over that shape.

Answer (score 1):

Try this circle code made using **html5 svg**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style="margin-left:100px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<circle cx="400" cy="400" r="200" stroke="black" class='yellow_cir' stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
<circle cx="400" cy="400" r="150" stroke="black" class='yellow_cir' stroke-width="2" fill="yellow" />
<circle cx="400" cy="400" r="100" stroke="black" class='yellow_cir' stroke-width="2" fill="cyan" />
<circle cx="400" cy="400" r="50" stroke="black" class='yellow_cir' stroke-width="2" fill="cyan" />
  <defs>
     <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
      stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(100,100,105);stop-opacity:1" />
    </radialGradient>

     <radialGradient id="grad2" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);
      stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(10,10,105);stop-opacity:1" />
    </radialGradient>
  </defs>
</svg> 



</div>
</body>
</html> 
<style type="text/css">


.yellow_cir:hover{ fill:url("#grad2");cursor:pointer;
}
.yellow_cir
{
    fill:url("#grad1");
}
</style>
```

Comment: with this i revealed that we can use svg instead of canvas but how can we implement the scrolling to the svg context is we need to see the timeline exeeding the horrizontal size of the svg area

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jquery plugin to generate and display a [Timeline](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/timeline).
This might just make your work faster.